# how to send and retrieve custom form info through paypal IPN?

Tags: php, forms, paypal

It seems that Paypal limits what what information can be retrieved by the paypal IPN php file after the user pays. I want users to be able to make an username and password that they will use to log in to my website before they click the paypal checkout button. After they pay, my paypal IPN php file will retrieve their username and password and place them into my mysql database. Is this possible? I want to make registration as easy as possible for the users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could use the `custom` field by which you could also retrieve in your ipn post back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of custom fields that you can add to your form that paypal will return no matter what you sue them. however i would recommend saving the data locally, before sending the rest of  to paypal, to do this you either nee to use AJAX to submit part of the form to a php script or pre-possessing the form data before sending to paypal via curl.